# Create Record type in Contact tab and How to upload Contacts using Data Loder?

Tags: trigger, community, data-loader, record-type

I crate a Record type **Sales Contact** in "Contact" and assign a **Sales Contact Layout**  And create a Record Type **Enterprise** in "Account" and assign a **Enterprise Account Layout**.

When I upload contact in Sales Contact, It will create only Account and send errors like :

**Contacts:**
Created: 0
Rejected: 2

**Accounts:**
Created: 2
Rejected: 0

Can anyone help me how do I relate Contact to Account, and upload 300 records in "Sales Contact" in Contact and "Enterprise" in Account

Thank You!

Comment: What fields are on your file? Are you using the import wizard or DataLoader?  The dataloader requires you to create the accounts then import the contacts after with the AccountId.  If you using the Import Wizard, did you map the contact fields?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you view [Data Import How To's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnobS_RgN7JZaD_Fq8uh3b2AA8olsj1Qk), a short series of YouTube videos prepared by Salesforce on how to prepare your data and which tools to use for different kinds of Data Import. `Contacts` are related to `Account` which means that the `Account` needs to be inserted first.

They'll both also need to have the `record type` included in the CSV files you'll be importing unless you want to convert them later. The `Contacts` will also need to have a reference to the `Account` that Salesforce can recognize which you'll "map" to the appropriate field when you import it using some kind of external Id or other reference.

The videos will clearly explain how to prepare your data for import to make certain all of the above happens without errors.